# Trying to re-enable disabled custom add-ins for outlook, but can't find in registry editor

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am building a custom add-in for outlook, but I couldn't use the add-in after adding to outlook, because it is inactive(disabled).

[image]

I created a custom add-in by following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator#create-the-add-in-project).

But after creating the add-in, I was not able to sideload using `npm start`.

So I used this. `npm run dev-server`.

And I added the add-in to outlook by following this guide - [outlook on desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing#outlook-on-the-desktop).

At this moment, the custom add-in I just added is inactive, so I tried to troubleshoot this.

The documentation says I should go to File->Slow and Disabled COM Add-ins and enable the disabled add-in, but there were nothing in the option.

[image]

And also I tried to find add-ins in the system registry and set to enable always, but I couldn't find the added custom add-in either.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/Concepts/Getting-Started/support-for-keeping-add-ins-enabled

Did I miss anything or ...?

Even if the add-in is active, but it doesn't work.

I signed in with my work email and am using the latest version of Office365.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing web and COM add-ins for Outlook. It seems a web add-in was created using the yeoman generator and sideloaded into your Outlook account. Note, web add-ins work for Exchange profiles only (including O365). Most probably you are trying to run the add-in against a non-Exchange account in Outlook.

But the troubleshooting steps described in the post are related to COM add-ins only (VSTO based ones too).

Comment: Asfafiev Thanks for answering to my question, but I am using Microsoft Exchange profile, and sometimes the add-in is active, but not working.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working in web, then you mean I should build two add-ins with the same functionality in both web and desktop separately?

Comment: There is no need to develop both kind of add-ins unless you need to get specific features available only for COM add-ins.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. Then how to figure this out? How to enable the add-in so as to use in desktop?

Comment: There are multiple reasons why your add-in can be inactive in Outlook. First of all, I'd suggest selecting any item in the inbox. Web add-ins work in the context of a specific item. Also you need to make sure the manifest is well formed. You can try to sideload the add-in anew.

Comment: I appreciate your help! I will try again.